# How to disable or hide assign/redirect button if the ID already exist in other table on django

Tags: python, html, django

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    active_choices = [('Yes', 'Yes'),
                      ('No', 'No')]
    active = models.CharField(
        max_length=6, choices=active_choices, default='Yes')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**The other one is:**

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)   
    is_active = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.patient.name
```

**In the Views.py**

```
@login_required
def PatientView(request):
    form = PatientModelForm(request.POST or None)
    patients = Patient.objects.order_by('-id')
    ticket_list = Ticket.objects.filter(is_active=0)
    total = patient_list.count()       
    if form.is_valid():
        obj.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Patient was added successfully.')
        return redirect('/dashboard/patient')
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'patients ': patients ,    
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/patient.html', context)
```

**The other view for ticket:**

```
@login_required
def TicketToGenerateView(request, pk):
    ticket = get_object_or_404(Patient, pk=pk)

    form = TicketModelForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():    
        obj.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Patient assigned successfully.')
        return redirect('/dashboard/ticket')

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'ticket': ticket,
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/ticket.html', context)
```

So I want to hide this bellow link button if patient.pk already exist in the Ticket model and is_active = 1 So it displays all rows with assign link button.

```
<a href="{% url 'dashboard:ticket_to' patient.pk %}" name="doctor" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Assign to a Doctor"> <span class=" fa fa-user-md "></span> </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom **template tag**

Create a `templatetags` *package* under your app directory; So you should have these inside your app directory:

```
templatetags
templatetags/__init__.py
templatetags/check_patient.py
```

Next, add the following to code to `<your_app_dir>/templatetags/check_patient`:

```
from django import template
from <your_app>.models import Ticket

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def check_patient_already_exists(request, pk):
    return Ticket.objects.filter(patient_pk=pk, is_active=1).exists()
```

and in your template:

```
{% load check_patient %}

{% if not check_patient_already_exists patient.pk %}

    <a href="{% url 'dashboard:ticket_to' patient.pk %}" name="doctor" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Assign to a Doctor"> <span class=" fa fa-user-md "></span> </a>

{% endif %}
```

Check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/) for more info

Comment: Afrer placing everything it says: **Unused 'patient.pk' at end of if expression.**  _Error during template rendering_

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue? There should be something wrong with your `if` statement.

Comment: Yes I did, but here I'm using nested for loop and if statment:   `{% if not queryset %} {% for patient in patients %} {% if not check_patient_already_exists patient.pk %}
                        <a href="{% url 'dashboard:ticket_to' patient.pk %}" name="doctor" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm"
                            data-toggle="tooltip" title="Assign to a Doctor"> <span class=" fa fa-user-md "></span> </a>
                        {% endif %} {% endfor %}{% endif %}`